# Pandas - interpolation on the lines

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a DataFrame with a few empty columns and I want to do an interpolation on each line to fill them. Here is an example:

`3       12      18    24      36      120    180    360
2018-01-03 00:00:00  1.3913  1.8034  NaN  1.9313  2.0149  2.4471  NaN  2.7855
2018-01-04 00:00:00  1.3964  1.8007  NaN  1.9515   2.037  2.4525  NaN  2.7863
2018-01-05 00:00:00  1.3936  1.7927  NaN  1.9599  2.0596  2.4763  NaN  2.8105
2018-01-08 00:00:00  1.4063  1.7797  NaN  1.9579   2.057    2.48  NaN  2.8113
2018-01-09 00:00:00  1.4322   1.777  NaN  1.9641   2.071  2.5384  NaN  2.8824`

When I use `interpolate` method with `axis=1` I am getting the same DataFrame back, with no interpolation whatsoever. I've tried looping through all the lines  and changing the interpolation method as well, but I still get no interpolation back. **Any guesses on what this may be?**

Here is an exemple code:

`ExampleDF.iloc[-1]
Out[42]: 
3      1.4322
12      1.777
18        NaN
24     1.9641
36      2.071
120    2.5384
180       NaN
360    2.8824`

`test.iloc[-1].interpolate(method='cubic')
Out[43]: 
3      1.4322
12      1.777
18        NaN
24     1.9641
36      2.071
120    2.5384
180       NaN
360    2.8824`

Comment: Are you assign your results of your interpolate back to your dataframe variable... ie.   `df = df.interpolate(axis=1)`  Or using the inplace=True?

Comment: Please post `ExampleDF.info()` and `ExampleDF.iloc[-1].dtype`.

Comment: @ScottBoston I've tried both, but with no sucess

Comment: @GustavoAmarante unutbu has an idea.  Are those numeric dtype columns in your dataframe?

Comment: @unutbu I found the problem, thanks tou your request. the values on my Dataframe were `dtype: object`. I used the `astype` method to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sample = [[1.3913, 1.8034, NaN, 1.9313, 2.0149, 2.4471, NaN, 2.7855],[1.3964, 1.8007, NaN, 1.9515,  2.037, 2.4525, NaN, 2.7863],[1.3936, 1.7927, NaN, 1.9599, 2.0596, 2.4763, NaN, 2.8105],[1.4063, 1.7797, NaN, 1.9579,  2.057, 2.48, NaN, 2.8113],[1.4322,  1.777, NaN, 1.9641,  2.071, 2.5384, NaN, 2.8824]]

df = pd.DataFrame(sample)

df.iloc[-1].interpolate(method='cubic')
```

Works well. The data frame seems to be mis-defined.